# Get data using python sockets from firebase

Tags: python, sockets, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to access my database on Firebase using the sockets library instead of the python requests library. Bellow I have a simple example that returns

```
b'Invalid Firebase Request'
Time 0.10938119888305664
```

I'm mostly trying to reduce the latency between my client ('which should post not get') and the fire base server

```
import socket
import ssl
import time
import requests



HOST = '<my database link>.firebaseio.com'  
PORT = 443    
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    ss = ssl.wrap_socket(s, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
    ss.connect((HOST, PORT))
    for i in range(1):
        ts = time.time()    
        request = "GET /<A database child>.json \nHost: "+ HOST+"\n\n"
        ss.send(request.encode())
        result = ss.recv(4096)
        #print (result)
        while (len(result)>0):
            print (result)
            result = ss.recv(4096)
        print ('Time '+ str(time.time()-ts))
```

also when I increase the range above 1 the program doesn't make multiple requests. why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to send a malformed HTTP(S) request. A valid HTTP 1.1 request looks like this:

```
request = "GET /<A database child>.json HTTP/1.1\r\n" \
          "Host: " + HOST + "\r\n"                    \
          "Connection: keep-alive\r\n"                \
          "\r\n"
```

After receiving an invalid request server apparently closes the connection, thus you can not read from (nor write to) socket `ss` anymore.

Comment: awersome! i get a stable open connection :D